# Bash - Extract Matching String from GZIP Files Is Running Very Slow

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu

Complete novice in Bash. Trying to iterate thru 1000 gzip files, may be GNU parallel is the solution??

```
#!/bin/bash
ctr=0
echo "file_name,symbol,record_count" > $1
dir="/data/myfolder"
for f in "$dir"/*.gz; do

  gunzip -c $f | while read line;
  do
    str=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f1`
    if [ "$str" == "H" ]; then
      if [ $ctr -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$f,$sym,$ctr" >> $1
      fi
      ctr=0
      sym=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f3`
      echo $sym
    else
      ctr=$((ctr+1))
    fi
  done
done
```

Any help to speed the process will be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: could you explain what you're trying to do with those 1000 files ?

Comment: extracting a string from each Gzipped text file, from 3rd pipe delimited space of any line starting with "H"

Comment: Generic advise when people ask about performance is to measure. In other words, use a profiler to find out which operations cost most of the time. A few things I'd consider here: Use `zcat` instead of `gunzip`. Use `zgrep -e '^H'` to find lines starting with "H". Another tool useful here could be `sed`. Other than that, in order to get this to run more parallel, I wouldn't use Bash.

Comment: I'd check if `zgrep -P '^H[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\K[^|]*' "$dir"/*.gz` isn't faster. It handles the unzipping, the 'does the line start by H' filter and the third field extraction in a single command.

Comment: >Aaron, that was a great tip....I am extracting all H rows much faster now
I didn't mention another thing that my code was doing, I am counting number of rows between consecutive H rows

>Ulrich....looking at python multiprocessing as an alternative

Comment: Then I would pipe the output of `zcat` (or your current `gunzip -c` which AFAIK is identical) to `awk` and use an `awk` script that would handle the counter variable, the 'does the line start with H' and the expected output. This probably wouldn't be as efficient as the above `zgrep` command, but as you'd only invoke a single command per file (instead of 2 commands per line starting with H per file) I assume the performance increase would be noticeable

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
ctr=0
export ctr
echo "file_name,symbol,record_count" > $1
dir="/data/myfolder"
export dir

doit() {
  f="$1"
  gunzip -c $f | while read line;
  do
    str=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f1`
    if [ "$str" == "H" ]; then
      if [ $ctr -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$f,$sym,$ctr"
      fi
      ctr=0
      sym=`echo $line | cut -d"|" -f3`
      echo $sym >&2
    else
      ctr=$((ctr+1))
    fi
  done
}
export -f doit

parallel doit ::: *gz 2>&1 > $1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Bash `while read` loop is probably your main bottleneck here. Calling multiple external processes for simple field splitting will exacerbate the problem. Briefly,

```
while IFS="|" read -r first second third rest; do ...
```

leverages the shell's built-in field splitting functionality, but you probably want to convert the whole thing to a simple Awk script anyway.

```sh
echo "file_name,symbol,record_count" > "$1"
for f in "/data/myfolder"/*.gz; do
  gunzip -c "$f" |
  awk -F "\|" -v f="$f" -v OFS="," '
    /H/ { if(ctr) print f, sym, ctr
      ctr=0; sym=$3;
     print sym >"/dev/stderr"
     next }
  { ++ctr }'
done >>"$1"
```

This vaguely assumes that printing the lone `sym` is just for diagnostics. It should hopefully not be hard to see how this can be refactored if this is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Untested; please update the question with a small example input and expected output if you need testing.